# Login failed for user when adding connection to Server Explorer in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am connected to the company VPN and can access the database using Active Directory in SSMS:

[image]

However when I add a connection in Server Explorer in Visual Studio using the same credentials it throws login failed:

[image]

Do I need to configure VPN in Visual Studio?

EDIT: Using Active Directory Integrated

There is no error but the database dropdown is empty.

[image]

EDIT 2: Entered the db name in the combo box

[image]

Comment: Looks like you entered space in username maybe? Leave the usename and password blank And set Active Directory Integrated

Comment: @Charlieface Hi, there was no error but the db list is empty. I added the screenshot. I am not sure if the VPN is relevant but non-VPN dbs can be added.

Comment: Good, that means it's connected. And if you paste in the database name?

Comment: @Charlieface It says `Fail to parse XML blob`. Added screenshot.